# Retrive Column values from Google Fusion Table

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I am trying to retrieve all values (Suburb Names for that matter) from a column in Google's FusionTable (FT).
I can access the column itself using jQuery's ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/tables/'+ tableID +'/columns/Suburb?key=' + key,
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        suburbs_list = data;
    },
    error: function(data) {
        console.error(['error', data]);
    }
});
```

which returns

```
suburbs_list
Object {kind: "fusiontables#column", columnId: 0, name: "Suburb", type: "LOCATION"}
```

but I cannot find the way to access the values in this column. Is there a way or do I have to loop through each row and get the first column's value per row?

I've been through the documentation, but no word on this whatsoever.
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/reference/column

thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a query to fetch rows. You can specify which columns to get in the SELECT clause. See this help page for details: https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#WorkingRows

Comment: The actual code that resolves this is:

    `var queryURLHead =    'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=';`
    `var queryURLTail = '&jsonCallback=&';`
    `var query = "SELECT Suburb FROM " + tableID + " LIMIT 750";`
    `var queryURL = encodeURI(queryURLHead + query + queryURLTail + '&key=' + key);`
    `var jqxhr = $.get(queryURL, dataHandler, "jsonp");`

    `function dataHandler(d) {`
    `    console.log(d.rows[0]);`
    `    console.log(d.rows[0]);`
    `}`

Comment: sorry - doesn't matter what I do, I cannot get the code formatted ok in the comments :\